# Timezone reset on Amazon AMI update

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, timezone

I have a server set up through Amazon AWS.  It's Amazon's RHEL-based AMI.  When I initially booted up the machine, I set the proper timezone by creating a symlink:

`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime`

This works just fine, but whenever Amazon provides an update to their AMI the timezone automatically reverts to UTC.  Is there a way around this or does it have to be manually set after each update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. I think you need to update the `/etc/sysconfig/clock` config file to reflect your desired timezone in addition to updating `/etc/localtime` (which you've already done).

For me, this meant changing the default of:

```
ZONE="UTC"
UTC=true
```

To:

```
ZONE="Australia/Brisbane"
```

I won't really know if this has worked until the next time Amazon release an update, but I've got my fingers crossed ... :-)